# Load folder structure into tree-view JSON Object in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, file, treeview

I want to map a folder-structure including folders, json files and their contents into a tree-view like JSON object. I'd like to ask if anyone would provide me with a function i.e. loadFolder('/a') that would load the following folder structure ...

/a

/a/file1.json

/a/file2.json

/a/b/file1.json

/a/b/c

... would result into this JSON object:

```
    {
        path: "/a",
        name: "a",
        type: "folder",
        subnodes: [
            { 
                path: "/a/file1.json",
                name: "file1.json",
                type: "file",
                content: { 
                    // file content here
                }
            },
            { 
                path: "/a/file2.json",
                name: "file2.json",
                type: "file",
                content: { 
                    // file content here
                }
            },  
            {
                path: "/a/b",
                name: "b",
                type: "folder",
                subnodes: [
                    {
                        path: "/a/b/file1.json",
                        name: "file1.json",
                        type: "file",
                        content: { 
                            // file content here

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        path: "/a/b/c",
                        name: "c",
                        type: "folder",
                        subnodes: []
                    }           
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for example [this](https://github.com/wercker/directory-to-object) module you should easily get your folders structure. With that, simply iterate over array looking for files only and open each one of them using built-in `fs` module.